# Custom Tailored Weekly Moving Average Function

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am attempting to create a function that calculates the weekly moving average of a time series over a window of size n.

The input is a time series with a datetime index (where dates are on a daily frequency but some dates may be missing) and one column named "price". The goal is to return a time series with the same index where the price on date d is the average of the price on date d and the prices on the last day of each of the n-1 preceding weeks.

For instance, if the input dates are [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Monday] with corresponding prices [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and the window size is 2, the expected output for the prices should be [NaN, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4.5].

I have tried using the `resample('W')` method in Python as follows:

```
time_serie.resample('W').last().mean()
```

However, I am unsure how to accurately capture the current day in the calculation and integrate the window size into this method.

Comment: @Corralien No it should be 4.5 because the last day of the week before the price 5 is Wednesday with a price of 4. So (4+5)/2 = 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) over the week to extract the last value for the current week then [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) it forward (copy value from week N to week N+1) then use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to align dates:

```
ts['avg'] = (
    pd.merge_asof(ts['price'], ts['price'].resample('W').last().shift(),
                  left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='forward')
      .mean(axis=1, skipna=False)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> ts
            price  avg
2023-10-29      1  NaN
2023-10-30      2  1.5
2023-10-31      3  2.0
2023-11-01      4  2.5
2023-11-06      5  4.5

>>> ts['price'].resample('W').last().shift()
2023-10-29    NaN  # match with 2023-10-29
2023-11-05    1.0  # match with 2023-10-30, 2023-10-31, 2023-11-01
2023-11-12    4.0  # match with 2023-11-06
Freq: W-SUN, Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Minimal Working Example:

```
dt = ['2023-10-29', '2023-10-30', '2023-10-31', '2023-11-01', '2023-11-06']
ts = pd.DataFrame({'price': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, index=pd.to_datetime(dt))
print(ts)

# Output
            price
2023-10-29      1  # Sunday
2023-10-30      2  # Monday
2023-10-31      3  # Tuesday
2023-11-01      4  # Wednesday
2023-11-06      5  # Monday
```

Comment: @Question1010. I updated my answer according your comment. I think you need a rolling window of 6 days (not 7)?

Comment: The thing is that I think it just works in that particular case. If there are more values it will not work. Because what I want to do is basically: for day d it's the average between price at day d, and price of the last day of the n-1 week before.

Comment: for example with n=2 and Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Monday if the prices were: [2, 2, 3, 4, 6], then the result should be [NaN, (2+2)/2=2, (3+2)/2=2.5, (4+2)/2=3, (4+6)/2=5]

Comment: @Question1010. Sorry for my late answer. I got it :-) I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

Use .rolling().mean() method to your column, eg:

```
data = {'date': '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-06',
        'price': 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['ma_2'] = df['price'].rolling(2).mean()
```

Remember, to delete any 'NaN' values in your 'price' column

Next, take your frame and shift it amount of days you want (if you need week then place 7) with method .shift()

```
df['previous_week_date'] = df['date'].shift(7)
df['previous_week_price'] = df['price'].shift(7)
```

and then perform any calculation you want on this df, later on if you want to delete shifted dates, just delete column

I hope it is what you want to achieve, as I was not sure if I understood correctly desired output